# What happend to the Brompton "M" line?

Tags: brompton

What happened to the Brompton M-Line of bicycles?

I have a Brompton Model M6R, which (as indicated by the first letter of the model) is in the Brompton's M-Line of their bicycles. But when I checked [Brompton's website](https://us.brompton.com/bikes) (in 2023), I no longer see any listings for an "M-Line" model.

I tried googling for information about the change, but I couldn't find any articles about it.

Does Brompton still sell the M-Line models? If not, why?

Comment: This is a good article that describes the (now-changed?) Brompton model lines from 2020. But I can't find anything that describes the new models, what was deleted, what was added, and why https://bromptonbikes.com.au/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-brompton-model-codes/

Answer (score 2):

The new "line" naming scheme is completely different from the old handlebar-gears-wheel naming system.  An M6R is basically equivalent to a C line explore with roller rack and mid handlebars.

https://us.brompton.com/bikes

Comment: Is there a general pattern that can be applied to, say, the M3L as well?

Comment: Is there any article or PDF memo that Brompton published to dealers to explain this transition to translate other lines as well? Like @DavidW's M3L, for example.